# what are the spherical coordinates

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

What are the spherical coordinates of the point whose rectangular coordinates are 
(3 ,   1  , 4 ) ?

I got that [image]=sqrt26 but I could not find the values for the others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\theta=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)$$
$$\phi=\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{z}{r}\right)$$

Where I am using the convention that $\phi$ is the polar angle.

Comment: You should really specify which is the azimuthal angle and which is the polar angle since different people use different conventions.  In this case $\theta$ is the azimuthal angle and $\phi$ is the polar angle.  Sorry, apparently I didn't know which was which, polar angle:http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolarAngle.html azimuth: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Azimuth.html

Comment: Added that. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

In terms of Cartesian:

Cylindrical coordinates:
\begin{eqnarray}
\rho&=&\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\\
\theta&=&\tan^{-1}{\frac{y}{x}}\\
z&=&z
\end{eqnarray}

Spherical coordinates:
\begin{eqnarray}
r&=&\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}\\
\theta&=&\cos^{-1}{\frac{z}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}}\\
\phi&=&\tan^{-1}{\frac{y}{x}}
\end{eqnarray}